# Bash regular expression if statement

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, it just doesn't make sense the reason its not working:

This one I do get the SSH result as expected

```
if [ "Hennopsview" != "2 - LAN" ] && [ "Hennopsview" != "1 - WAN" ] \
           && [ "Hennopsview" != "Cross Connect" ]; then
    if [[ "Hennopsview" =~ /pptp/g ]]; then
        echo "No Match 2"
    else
        ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ':put [/interface eoip get [/interface eoip find name="Hennopsview"] remote-address]'
    fi
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

The following one however doesn't give me the Match 2 echo

```
if [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "2 - LAN" ] && [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "1 - WAN" ] \
            && [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "Cross Connect" ]; then
    if [[ "<pptp-hennopsview>" =~ /pptp/g ]]; then
        echo "No Match 2"
    else
        ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ':put [/interface eoip get [/interface eoip find name="<pptp-hennopsview>"] remote-address]'
    fi
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

What is wrong with this regular expression?

The following however fixes the second request

```
if [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "2 - LAN" ] && [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "1 - WAN" ] \
            && [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "Cross Connect" ]; then
    if [[ "<pptp-hennopsview>" =~ [pptp] ]]; then
        echo "No Match 2"
    else
        ssh admin@154.127.117.218 ':put [/interface eoip get [/interface eoip find name="<pptp-hennopsview>"] remote-address]'
    fi
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

but then breaks the original one

```
if [ "Hennopsview" != "2 - LAN" ] && [ "Hennopsview" != "1 - WAN" ] \
            && [ "Hennopsview" != "SDA - Cross Connect" ]; then
    if [[ "Hennopsview" =~ [pptp] ]]; then
        echo "No Match 2"
    else
        ssh admin@154.127.117.218 ':put [/interface eoip get [/interface eoip find name="Hennopsview"] remote-address]'
    fi
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

I do understand that using "[pptp]" is a character match and not word. By why when replacing "[" with "/" doesn't fix the issue?

Comment: The [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has some tips for making your question minimal and easy to answer.  Perhaps review that for next time!

Answer (score 1):

`/pptp/g` will match the string `".../pptp/g..."`. The operator `=~` takes on its right side the regular expression, without any separators: <strike>no quotes,</strike> no slashes. If you want to find `pptp`, that is the only thing that should be there:

```
[[ "<pptp-hennopsview>" =~ pptp ]]
```

is what you probably wanted to do.

EDIT: I don't know why I wrote "no quotes".

Comment: Also not sure what you would hope for `/g` to accomplish if this really *were* the format you would use.  In `sed`,  the `s` command has a `/g` option which says to substitute every match on a line, instead of just the first; but for matching, you hardly care whether there is one match, or more than one.

Comment: Also `[pptp]` means *contains p or p or t or p*, or more simply, *contains either p or t*.  The `[ ]` notation only matches a single character.

Comment: @cdarke: Indeed. It is what you would normally write in most other languages as `/[pptp]/` (well, as `/[pt]/`, really :P). It just looks weird here because `bash` doesn't want your slashes, which most other languages use to construct regexp literals.

Comment: Most languages?  Not grep, C, C++, C#, Java, Python, or Ruby.  SFAIK only sed, awk, perl, and PHP PCRE use the / / (the old PHP RE engine didn't).  There is a direct line of evolution between those that do - they share a common gene.

Comment: @cdarke: Ruby uses slash literals (although there are also other ways to write it, used less commonly). And you missed JavaScript, which is a quite important language today. Also, C, C++, Java and Python *don't have* regexp literals: they use string literals, which they then convert into regexps or use as regexps. Almost all languages that *do* have regexp literals use slashes (elisp being a notable exception, AFAIK).

Comment: Fair comments, I'm not into JavaScript.  Perl works slightly differently in that it does use strings but the / / default to the match (m) operator.  I think most will allow any non-meta character to be used as a delimiter, the most confusing I ever saw in Perl was a comma. `s,a,b,g`

Comment: @cdarke: Yep, you're right, in sed and perl, `//`, as synonym for `m//`, is an operator, not actually a literal. (The alternatives in Ruby are also taken from there: `/foo/` is synonymous with `%r{foo}`, `%r,foo,`...)

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved my issue:

```
if [ "<pptp-Hamanskraal>" != "2 - LAN" ] && [ "<pptp-Hamanskraal>" != "1 - WAN" ] && [ "<pptp-hennopsview>" != "Cross Connect" ]; then if [[ "<pptp-hennopsview>" =~ "pptp-" ]]; then ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ':put [/interface pptp-server get [/interface pptp-server find name="<pptp-hennopsview>"] client-address ]'; else ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ':put [/interface eoip get [/interface eoip find name="<pptp-hennopsview>"] remote-address]'; fi else echo "No Match"; fi
```

The following resolved all my issues

```
[[ "<pptp-hennopsview>" =~ "pptp-" ]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you comparing literals?  Those tests will ALWAYS give exactly the same results if they don't contain variables.